# How could I make the setTimeout(function(){message.delete();} function delete a Discord Message Embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm getting into javascript, or more specifically discord.js and I've decided to try to make a moderation bot. I created a ban command, and after it bans the user, it sends a message embed showing the info of the ban, such as the reasoning of the ban, the user's tag, etc. I've decided to use the setTimeout function to delete the embed after 5 seconds. But, I can't figure out how to. I know exactly how to use the setTimeout function, it's just that I don't know what to do to delete the embed. Here's my code:

```
            let kickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Member Kicked!')
            .setColor("GREEN")
            .addFields(
                {name: `Member:`, value: `${memberTarget}`},
                {name: `Moderator`, value: `${message.author}`},
                {name: `Reason`, value: `${kickReason}`}
            )
            await message.channel.send({embeds: [kickEmbed]})
            setTimeout(function(){
                kickEmbed.delete();
            }, 5000);
```

The problem is the "kickEmbed.delete();" part. I don't know what to put there. kickEmbed doesn't work, msg doesn't work, message doesn't work either. Here's an error if that helps: `'kickEmbed.delete' is not a function`

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: SetTimeout will forever call a global value that may or may be set. You should be passing the variable through the Timeout and calling it correctly. As for API usage someone else who uses it more needs to chime in but KickEmbed can be invalid five seconds from now or be a different value entirely so it's invalid coding when dealing with masses do correct.

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function(newArg) {
  newArg.delete();
}, 5000, KickEmbed);
```

I don't like making posts but first part to solution is understanding what you send to a timeout. If you send no arguments it's a global call and if that updates/changes or is removed errors in code occur so passing the value you intend on usage is optimal here. Second part is discord and its proper usage. GL

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are running it on the `MessageEmbed` object itself. Make it so you save the sent message to a variable, rather than the embed object

```js
let kickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Member Kicked!')
            .setColor("GREEN")
            .addFields(
                {name: `Member:`, value: `${memberTarget}`},
                {name: `Moderator`, value: `${message.author}`},
                {name: `Reason`, value: `${kickReason}`}
            )
            let sentMessage = await message.channel.send({embeds: [kickEmbed]})
            setTimeout(function(){
                sentMessage.delete();
            }, 5000)
```